# Jquery leave only two numbers after decimal point

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, decimal

Been looking for this a while now, most questions include same answers which I have tried and it did not work for my case, hence why I am posting this. Now my script returns several numbers and I want to leave those numbers and 2 numbers after the decimal point, now the problem is that I have another script that adds commas to those numbers, so for example, I might get following numbers.

```
56,883.90,607,219,945
5,327.078,363,188,421
1688.7000000000003
2,739.272
```

Now I have tried several stuff, including `Number(number).toFixed(2)`, etc. But it would cut off some parts, for example.

1. first number above would return > `"56.00"`, While I need it to return `56,883.90`
2. Would return > `"5.00"`, While I need `5,327.07`
3. would return what I am expecting `"1688.70"`
4. Would return `"2.00"` instead of `2,739.27`

Now I understand where the issue is, it takes comma and turns number afterwards, is there way to specifically grab only 2 numbers after the DOT?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `56,883.90,607,219,945` this is not a valid number? So is the second one `5,327.078,363,188,421`. Is there a reason why the numbers are formatted as such? That is because that is not how numbers are represented at all. Look into whatever script/logic that is generating those, and fix that instead: this feels like an XY problem to me.

Comment: Once the commas are in there, they aren't numbers anymore, they're strings, so you'll have to use a RegEx to fix the issue.

Comment: `Number("56,883.90")` would return `NaN` because of the comma.

Comment: `var number = "56,883.90,607,219,945".split(",", 2);
alert(number);`

Comment: @Terry Yeah, I will get to that, sorry about that. It's basically a script which adds comma after each 3 numbers. But back onto the tracks, if the number was for example 5,327.078 and I used Number(5,327.078).toFixed(2); It would still return 5.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Regex**:

```
'56,883.90,607,219,945'.replace(/(\..{2}).*/,'$1')
```

---

Which matches all of your expected results:

```
56,883.90,607,219,945  => 56,883.90
5,327.078,363,188,421  => 5,327.07
1688.7000000000003     => 1688.70 (it will not add comma)
2,739.272              => 2,739.27
```

```js
function changeToNumber(str) {
  return str.replace(/(\..{2}).*/, '$1');
}

var input = ['56,883.90,607,219,945',
  '5,327.078,363,188,421',
  '1688.7000000000003',
  '2,739.272'
]

input.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log(changeToNumber(value));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `,` from the number string to parse the full number. Use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to remove `,` from the string.

```
Number('5,327.078'.replace(/,/g, ''))
```

```js
console.log(Number('5,327.078'.replace(/,/g, '')).toFixed(2));
```